# python tkinter checkboxes get ticked at once

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

why do both checkboxes get checked when I only click one? The checkboxes on the right and in a different Frame, as well as the ones on the left. The variables are also different for each checkbox. Anyone has any idea what might cause this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWXYj.jpg

```
# Child of [right_content] {FILTER}
filter_by = Frame(right_content,
                  width=380,
                  height=50,
                  padx=5,
                  pady=5)
filter_by.pack(fill='x')

# Child of [filter_by] {RIGHT}
filter_by_right = Frame(filter_by,
                        width=190)
filter_by_right.pack(side='right')

# Child of [filter_by] {LEFT}
filter_by_left = Frame(filter_by,
                       width=190,
                       padx=10,
                       pady=5)
filter_by_left.pack(side='left')

firstname_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_left, text='Search by Firstname')
firstname_chk.pack()
surname_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_left, text='Search by Surname')
surname_chk.pack()
badgeid_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_right, text='Search by BadgeID')
badgeid_chk.pack()
position_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_right, text='Search by Position')
position_chk.pack()
```

Comment: Please share the code of that checkboxes and your variables you are using.

Comment: Please share more info on the question. Without knowing your code we cannot know what is wrong, however, it is possible that you have assigned the same variable to the checkboxes in the same row so that when the variable changes by one of the checkboxes the other adapts itself to the variable as well.

Comment: @Atlas435, I have put the code now.

Comment: You did not use any tkinter variables on the checkbuttons.

Comment: @acw1668 what do you mean?

Comment: There is an `variable` option of `Checkbutton` to assign a tkinter variable to control the check state of `Checkbutton`.  But you did not use it.

Comment: @Kristler as acw mentioned, there are no variables in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not specify the `variable` option of the `Checkbutton`, the default is used which is the name of the `Checkbutton` within its parent (i.e. the last element of the button window's path name).

As `firstname_chk` and `badgeid_chk` are the first `Checkbutton` in `filter_by_left` and `filter_by_right` respectively, their name are both `!checkbutton`.  So they share the same tkinter variable created implicitly and their states will be changed simultaneously.

Same apply on `surname_chk` and `position_chk`.

You need to assign different tkinter variables to those `Checkbutton`.

```py
var1 = BooleanVar()
firstname_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_left, text='Search by Firstname', variable=var1)
firstname_chk.pack()

var2 = BooleanVar()
surname_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_left, text='Search by Surname', variable=var2)
surname_chk.pack()

var3 = BooleanVar()
badgeid_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_right, text='Search by BadgeID', variable=var3)
badgeid_chk.pack()

var4 = BooleanVar()
position_chk = Checkbutton(filter_by_right, text='Search by Position', variable=var4)
position_chk.pack()
```